# React-native for Android Automotive

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-automotive

This seems like a plain enough question, but I genuinely cannot find a straight answer anywhere else.

IS it currently possible to use React Native to develop native apps runnable in Android Automotive?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure myself, but under "application fundamentals" in the Android Developers Docs it says:

"Android apps can be written using Kotlin, Java, and C++ languages"
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals

So I'm guessing the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

According to the automotive guidelines (https://source.android.com/docs/devices/automotive/driver_distraction/guidelines) one would need to be able to configure on a per-android-activity basis if it is distraction-optimised or not. I'm not sure how this would be possible with react native.